# React SecureServer runs but throws SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP in browser

Tags: php, openssl, ratchet, reactphp

We've set up a secure socket server, which was working before securing it with SecureServer. Running the php script succeeds but when trying to connect from application, the browser throws a SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP error.

Probably something is wrong in our php script. does someone know how to tackle this?

Code we have:

```
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    new React\Socket\SecureServer(
        $webSock,
        $loop,
        array(
            'local_cert' => 'xxx',
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            // Not sure what to put in ciphers ??
            'ciphers' => 'EECDH+AES:EDH+AES:-SHA1:EECDH+AES256:EDH+AES256:AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP:!LOW:!MD5:!RC4:!MEDIUM'
        )
    )
);
```

Some articles suggest of fiddling with browser configs, but the connection should be available to all visitors.. (without the fiddling)

---

EDIT: We used SecureServer at the wrong place, added answer with corrected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using React\Socket\SecureServer with Ratchet:

```
// Set up secure React server
$webSock = new React\Socket\SecureServer(
    new React\Socket\Server($loop),
    $loop,
    array(
        'local_cert' => 'xxxx/combined.pem',
        //'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false
    )
);
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect (127.0.0.1 || 0.0.0.0)

// Ratchet magic
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);
```

Comment: As of the version cboden/ratchet 0.4.3, the method listen() does not exists any longer in an instance of a SecureServer.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur when the list of [cipher suites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite) used by the server has no entries in common with the ones used by the client, or browser. I would take a look at your `'ciphers'` line and ensure you list the suites correctly, and that you use [modern suites](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Modern_compatibility) likely to be available in modern browsers.

The OpenSSL documentation on cipher suites has a [full list](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES) of available suites and the [proper format](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT) for specifying them. In particular, I find it easier to list the suites explicitly, rather than your current notation, which makes it easy to accidentally exclude all or most of the suites. You could also just specify a family, such as `TLSv1.2` in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your time. However, changing the line to `'ciphers' => 'TLSv1.2'` does not help solving the error.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly listing the suites, like in the Mozilla wiki linked above? Also, knowing the OS, and OpenSSL versions might help nail this down.

Comment: SSL Version: OpenSSL/1.0.1e , PHP 5.5.38 on a Linux server.

Comment: I tried with string `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256` and it still throws that error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162112/discussion-between-afrothundr-and-brainfeeder), where I have addressed this.

Comment: Upvoted for your time spent on this. We got it working.